# Changing the algorithm from writing to reading .txt or .xls to JTable

Tags: java, jtable, xls

Could you tell me how can I load JTable from .txt or .xls file?
I used the algoriithm below to save JTable content as .xls:

```
public void saveTable()throws Exception
{

    BufferedWriter bfw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Data.xls"));
  for(int i = 0 ; i < jTable1.getColumnCount() ; i++)
  {
    bfw.write(jTable1.getColumnName(i));
    bfw.write("\t");
  }

  for (int i = 0 ; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++)
  {
    bfw.newLine();
    for(int j = 0 ; j < jTable1.getColumnCount();j++)
    {
      bfw.write((String)(jTable1.getValueAt(i,j)));
      bfw.write("\t");;
    }
  }
  bfw.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Read the first line from the file into a String variable.
2. Use the `String.split(...)` method to split the string into an Array containing the column names.
3. Create a `DefaultTableModel` using the `new DefaultTableModel(columnName, 0)` constructor.
4. Read the next line in the file into a String variable
5. Use the `String.split(...)` method to split the string into an Array containing the data for each column
6. Use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to add the Array from step 5 to the TableModel
7. Repeat steps 4-6 until all the records have been read.